# Having problem to connect on sftp after moving sftp to AWS through camel

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel, sftp, edi

I'm having problems to connect on the sftp through springboot camel app. This started happening after we moved our sftp to AWS . Now, I have a temporary server host which looks like this `s-add03ac9b.server.transfer.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`, I can connect in there by using for instance FileZilla but if I try to connect using the app, this is the error I get:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: s-add03ac9b.server.transfer.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/testFolder?username=myUser&password=myPassword&disconnect=true&maxMessagesPerPoll=50&initialDelay=1s&delay=1s&timeout=3000&move=done&moveFailed=failed, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
```

, and here is the route itself, I changed it a bit to be more readable

```
        from("s-add03ac9b.server.transfer.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/testFolder?username=myUser&password=myPassword&disconnect=true&maxMessagesPerPoll=50&initialDelay=1s&delay=1s&timeout=3000&move=done&moveFailed=failed")
            .setHeader(Headers.CONFIGURATION.name(), constant(routeConfiguration))
            .setHeader("filenameModify").constant(modifyFileNames).setHeader("fileExtension")
            .constant(fileExtension).choice().when(PredicateBuilder.and(header("filenameModify").isEqualTo(true), header("fileExtension").isNotNull()))
            .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,
                    simple("${file:name.noext}-${date:in.header.CamelFileLastModified:ddMMyyyy-HHmmss}-${file:length}.${in.header.fileExtension}"))
            .end().idempotentConsumer(simple("${file:name}-${file:length}"), MemoryIdempotentRepository.memoryIdempotentRepository(1000))
            .log("Processing ${file:name}")
            .process(rawDataProcessor)
            .to((String) routeConfiguration.get(ConfigKey.END)).otherwise().log("File ${file:name} processed.").stop().end();
```

Do I need to add something else, maybe some dependency or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is having the same issue, I fixed it by adding an **sftp://** as a prefix in **from** part.